# Using javascript to display an output based on two html selects

Tags: javascript, html, select

I am trying to create a prixing calculator for a taxi service, providing an estimate between locations. So far I have this:

```
    <label for="Pickup Pricing">Pickup Location:</label>
<select name="Pickup-location" id="Pickup" onchange="pupdate()">
    <option value="">-Start Location-</option>
    <option value="Leighton Buzzard">Leighton Buzzard</option>
    <option value="Hockliffe">Hockliffe</option>
    <option value="Milton Keynes">Milton Keynes</option>
</select>

<br></br>

<label for="Destination Pricing">Destination:</label>
<select name="Destination" id="Destination" onchange="dupdate()">
    <option value="">-Destination-</option>
    <option value="Leighton Buzzard">Leighton Buzzard</option>
    <option value="Hockliffe">Hockliffe</option>
    <option value="Milton Keynes">Milton Keynes</option>
</select>

<h2 id="Pickupwrite"></h2><h2 id="Destinationwrite"></h2>

<script>
function pupdate() {
  var p = document.getElementById("Pickup");
  document.getElementById("Pickupwrite").innerHTML = "From " + p.value + " to ";
}

function dupdate() {
  var d = document.getElementById("Destination");
  document.getElementById("Destinationwrite").innerHTML = d.value + " is ";
}

</script>
```

This works to display my locations, I now need to create a way for the pricing to be looked up. I.e If Start is 'a' and destination is 'b' then price is 'x'.

I hope this makes sense, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: just create a 2d array where the columns are destinations and the rows are pick-up locations.  each cell contains the price.  Note the diagonal  from top left to bottom right would all be 0 or blank. then create a look up function

Answer (score 0):

As easy way you just need to use some `if else` statements 
like

```
    <label for="Pickup Pricing">Pickup Location:</label>
<select name="Pickup-location" id="Pickup" onchange="pupdate()">
    <option value="">-Start Location-</option>
    <option value="Leighton Buzzard">Leighton Buzzard</option>
    <option value="Hockliffe">Hockliffe</option>
    <option value="Milton Keynes">Milton Keynes</option>
</select>

<br></br>

<label for="Destination Pricing">Destination:</label>
<select name="Destination" id="Destination" onchange="dupdate()">
    <option value="">-Destination-</option>
    <option value="Leighton Buzzard">Leighton Buzzard</option>
    <option value="Hockliffe">Hockliffe</option>
    <option value="Milton Keynes">Milton Keynes</option>
</select>

<h2 id="Pickupwrite"></h2><h2 id="Destinationwrite"></h2>

<script>

var p="";
function pupdate() {
   p = document.getElementById("Pickup");
  document.getElementById("Pickupwrite").innerHTML = "From " + p.value + " to ";
}
function dupdate() {
  var d = document.getElementById("Destination");

  var result="";
  if(p.value == "Leighton Buzzard" && d.value == "Hockliffe"){
    result="Assalam";
  }
  else if(p.value == "Leighton Buzzard" && d.value == "Milton Keynes"){
    result="Merhaba";
  }
  else if(p.value == "Leighton Buzzard" && d.value == "Milton Keynes"){
   result="Hello";
  }
  else{
    result="no result";
    }

  document.getElementById("Destinationwrite").innerHTML = d.value + " is " + result;
}

</script>
```

Comment: That seems like an easy (hacky) way to go about it, I will give it a try!

Comment: Yes your are right, I showed this way becouse I thought that you are beginner in programming, normally you've been not check your important informations in client side of your program other wise all users will can see that

Comment: for that you most use an server side programming language like node.js , php ...etc

Comment: This works really well. Is there any way to have the result update when a destination has already been set and then the user changes the start?